# Difficulty centring a header banner image in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 5 and am struggling to make a header banner image centre when the viewport is wider than the banner.

I have tried `mx-auto` and also a custom CSS with `text-align: center`.  Neither option works. The header banner just stays stuck to the left of the screen.

Sample code: https://codepen.io/6a0a49af-a3f9-4e78-8ccf-91d8d1b1f102/pen/MWjxBRX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add to your element with the class names `mx-auto d-none d-md-flex`the flexbox property `justify-content: center`. Here is the example: https://codepen.io/lorian-grey/pen/XWjGPeL

Comment: Perfect. Thank you !